# Look over your shoulder vs look back

Tags: sentence-meaning

So I'm kind of confused.
What's the difference between
"He looked over his shoulder at us" and "He looked back at us"?

Comment: There is no difference, except that someone who 'looks back' might possibly turn their whole body round rather than just their head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a hard-and-fast rule, but I think you're more likely to *look over your shoulder* at ***something or someone catching up with you*** (it's ***approaching***), whereas you *look back* at ***some place where you were*** (it's now ***receding***).

Other than that, ***to look back*** is more common (and more "general-purpose", having a far less *specific* meaning) than ***to look over one's shoulder***. But note that we do often use the latter "metaphorically" *(He didn't try to escape from prison because he would always be looking over his shoulder fearing that the authorities would track him down)*.